# SHC executable not executing

Tags: bash, scripts

I have a simple bash script i.e.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Hello World!!"
```

Bash script file name is **random.sh**. I have encrypted it using SHC with the command:

```
/shc-3.8.9/shc -f random.sh
```

I get two more files in the directory i.e. **random.sh.x** and **random.sh.x.c**. Now when i run the executable with the command:

```
sudo ./random.sh.x
```

nothing happen and i do not see anything in the output. What can be the possible issue here ? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Using `3.8.9b-1build1` from the 18.04 repository, and **without** sudo (although I don't think that's relevant) it appears that the executable gets into an endless loop `execve`ing itself...

Comment: Yes, thats what i understood by googling this . So what is the solution ? @steeldriver

Comment: I don't know - it appears to complete successfully when run under `gdb`, so I'm not sure what's happening. Did you find a bug report?